# Finding Collocation using Apache OpenNLP

Tags: opennlp, collocation

I would like to find collocated words using Apache OpenNLP framework. By looking at the API, it seems there seems to no API for Collocation Finder. How to find the collocated words in a given sentences using OpenNLP. For example, in the below given sentence "Learn to create Machine Learning Algorithms in Python and R from two Data Science experts. Code templates included at San Jose", I want to find Machine Learning Algorthims and Data Science as one word.

Comment: are you able to resolve this, i am looking for solution for same issue.